# Absolute position of before - vertical center

Tags: html, css, center, pseudo-element

I'm trying to write a timeline. And I stopped at the moment of centering the pseudo-element vertically. I've tried already change top: 0, translate, translateY, vertical-align etc. Unfortunately, nothing wants to work properly.

```css
.time {
  width: 2px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #cfcfcf;
  display: inline-block;
}

.steps {
  width: 80%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 40px;
  .step-description {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    background-color: #7f7f7f;
    border-radius: 0.25rem;
    &:before {
      content: url("https://image.ibb.co/gxZuTc/step.png");
      position: absolute;
      margin-left: -53px;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row mt-5 ml-5">
  <div class="col-lg-7">
    <div class="time"></div>
    <div class="steps">
      <div class="step-description">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur dolorem cum nostrum nihil quaerat, ut ducimus totam quae consectetur qui blanditiis voluptas ipsam magni quod. Debitis veritatis eligendi placeat, labore!</p>
      </div>

      <div class="step-description">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur dolorem cum nostrum nihil quaerat, ut ducimus totam quae consectetur qui blanditiis voluptas </p>
      </div>

      <div class="step-description">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur dolorem cum nostrum nihil quaerat, ut ducimus</p>
      </div>

      <div class="step-description">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur dolorem cum nostrum nihil quaerat, ut ducimus totam quae consectetur qui blanditiis voluptas ipsam magni quod. Debitis veritatis eligendi placeat, labore!</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do from the question... What kind of timeline?

Comment: So please read with understanding because other users had no problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this 
CSS

```
.time {
  width: 2px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #cfcfcf;
  display: inline-block;
}

.steps {
  width: 80%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 40px;
  .step-description {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    background-color: #7f7f7f;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 0.25rem;
      &:before {
        content: url("https://image.ibb.co/gxZuTc/step.png");
        position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: i think the questioner is asking about the `pseudo` element

Comment: I dont think it can be done with the pseudo element. so i am suggesting a different approach

Comment: I have updated for pseudo element as well. It should also work

Comment: if this answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark and upvote. 
This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. 
There is no obligation to do this. :)

Comment: I don't have 15 reputations for give check mark. I can only give upvote.

Comment: you have already given check mark, you just need to upvote so that answerer gets additional 10 points

Comment: If the person who posted the question, upvotes the answer, it automatically gets a check mark. :) and I got one when you upvoted it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.time {
  width: 2px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #cfcfcf;
  display: inline-block;
 }

 .steps {
   width: 80%;
   display: inline-block;
   margin-left: 40px;
   .step-description {
     position: relative; // added
     border: 1px solid #000;
     background-color: #7f7f7f;
     border-radius: 0.25rem;
     &:before {
       content: url("https://image.ibb.co/gxZuTc/step.png");
       position: absolute;
       top: 50%; // added
       transform: translateY(-50%); // added
     }
   }
}
```